# An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module in angular while installing ngx-bootstrap

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I want to use ngx-bootstrap so command for it is `ng add ngx-bootstrap` inside Angular project but I am getting error as:

> An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module
> 'C:\Users\Nikhil\Desktop\angular-assignment2\node_modules@yarnpkg\lockfile\index.js'.
> Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
> See "C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-oquCOE\angular-errors.log" for
> further details.

Answer (score 1):

Deleted the

> package-lock.json

and

> node modules

and did `npm i` it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using an invalid command to add the `ngx-bootstrap` module. The `ng add` command is only used for Angular CLI commands that involve adding new components, modules, or other Angular structures to your project.

To add an existing module from a third party using `yarn`:

```
yarn add ngx-bootstrap
```

Comment: I am following documentation and there it is written the same command as I mentioned. And yes I am using angular CLI command

Comment: Can you link to the documentation that you are following?

Comment: https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/documentation

Comment: That documentation only references `npm` as a package manager option and it seems to imply that the `ng add` command acts as a wrapper for whatever package manager you are currently using with the project. Since the documentation doesn't offer `yarn` install commands, it's possible that there isn't support for installing `ngx-bootstrap` via `ng add` with `yarn`. I would recommend trying out the `yarn add ngx-boostrap` command or using `npm` instead.

Comment: Also, you can verify if the `ngx-bootstrap` dependency was successfully added with any of these commands by looking through your `package.json` file. If you are unsure of what to look for, please add the `package.json` contents to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem with an unconventional way. Uninstalling and reinstalling. In my case it was dependency with **constants-browserify**, and with ***npm uninstall constants-browserify*** and then ***npm install constants-browserify***. I solved the error